# How can I filter a query by a GenericForeignKey-Field using another query as possible values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have two apps: A simple message app and a ratings app to give points.

The points are Models that only have a generic foreign key and depending on how many of them exist there is a value assigned to everything I want.

```
class Point(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Now I thinking hard how to solve this: I have a list of things, e.g. messages:

```
class Message(models.Model):
  subject = models.CharField(max-length=255)
  body = models.TextField()


things = Point.objects.all()
```

So the goal is now to sort it by the number of assigned points to each object. This would be very easy using related query name. But then my message app will completely depend on the points app.

That's why I'd prefer to solve this using template tags only. I'm thinking of passing 'things' to a template tag and then sort this queryset by the points. It should look something like this:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def get_points_for_query(q):
  points = Point.objects.filter(content_object__in=q).prefetch_related('content_obj').order_by('pk')
  return points
```

Of course that doesn't work, because a generic foreign key cannot be used with "__in". But if I loop through the Queryset and call:

```
for obj in q:
  ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
```

It will cause a lot of work for my server. Is there a way to get the content type once for the query? I only intend to give queries to that tag that only query for a single type of content. Or is there a better way how to solve this without making these apps depend on each other?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you are worrying too much about coupling and not enough about cohesion. Make `Point` abstract and then make a `MessagePoint` class with a FK to `Message`. Generic relations, also known as `Polymorphic Associations` are rarely a good thing. Take a look at `SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the model of the queryset and then filter `Point` for that particular content type:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def get_points_for_query(q):
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(q.model)
    return Point.objects.filter(content_type=ct, object_id__in=q) \
                        .prefetch_related('content_obj').order_by('pk')
```

I'm not sure in the `object_id__in=q` clause.  If it will not work then try:

```
object_id__in=q.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

This should work fine.